# I get the same error on multiple systems and programs

Tags: netbeans, error-handling, windows-10

This is the program I'm trying to run. I have tried on two different systems and I get the exact same error message on both. I get the error message whenever I enter a price with a decimal e.g 4.2.

Code for the program:

```
package grocerylist;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GroceryList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float [] prices = new float [5];
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 prices: ");
        prices[0] = in.nextFloat();
        prices[1] = in.nextFloat();
        prices[2] = in.nextFloat();
        prices[3] = in.nextFloat();
        prices[4] = in.nextFloat();
        float total = prices[0] + prices[1] + prices[2] + prices[3] + prices[4];
        System.out.println("The total of the 5 items are: "+total);        
    }
}
```

The error message is on line 12 and goes like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
at grocerylist.GroceryList.main(GroceryList.java:21)
```

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1

Comment: You're using `prices[5]`, but the max index is 4. Also, please edit your code, it's partially showing as plain text. Also point out the line number reported by the error.

Comment: that's one thing @Marc but error is at `Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);` or subsequent `in.nextFloat();` parts

Comment: @Marc, I have removed the 5th index on prices. And the error is on line 12

Comment: @Hjalla1 The code works fine. are you entering '4.2.' or '4.2'?

Comment: @DualCoreMax, Well i just figured out the problem now. I was entering a full stop '.' instead of a comma before the decimal. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hjalla1 welcome and happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than what I first imagined. @DualCoreMax had the right mindset for the solution. Which was, when the user is typing in prices the user needs to use the comma sign to diffrenciate between the integer number and decimal number.

I seriously thought I had a way more major problem on my hands here, glad is is just a matter of my own stupidity. Thank you to everyone who came to help me, a first year student.